# How to get an image's width and height after scaling & rendering the react component

Tags: reactjs, width

How to get an image's width and height after scaling & rendering the react component

- After getting the image width and height. I have to update the state.

Comment: Pass a `ref` to the image and then using that ref, get the height and width inside the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// equivalent to componentDidMount
useEffect(() => {
  const height = document.getElementById("myImg").clientHeight
  const width =document.getElementById("myImg").clientWidth
  // update the state
}, [])
```

I'm not sure why do you have to get the width and height after rendering, it doesn't sound like to be a good thing.